# Finding the mean with two parameters in R

Tags: r

I need to find the mean of salinity in "cast 2" with the depth below 1000 meters in R.

Here's what I've tried:

```
mean(cast2(salinity2) & [depth2] < 1000)
```

I am a beginner at coding and I feel like I have the idea right, but my formatting is wrong, could someone please help? Also I have already assigned roles to "cast2", "salinity2", and "depth2" so I know those are working.

Comment: "Depth below 1000 meters" implies that the value should be > 1000, not < 1000 ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(cast2)`, if that is not too large. Also include any code tried and error messages.

Comment: @sunnymess – 
You haven't _included the data set links below._

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that `cast2` is a data frame with columns `salinity2`, `depth2`, and that "depth below 1000 meters" means "depth2 > 1000".

What you need to know here is how to do 2 things:

1. Subset a data frame based on the value of a variable
2. Extract a column from a data frame as a vector and perform a calculation on it

There are "base R" and [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) ways to do this. Here are the base R ways.

The second one first. To get the column `salinity2` from the data frame `cast2`:

```
cast2$salinity2
```

or

```
cast2[, "salinity2"]
```

To subset according to the value of `depth2` you can use:

```
cast2[cast2$depth2 > 1000, ]
```

or

```
subset(cast2, depth2 > 1000)
```

Putting them together to calculate the mean:

```
mean(cast2[cast2$depth2 > 1000, "salinity2"])
```

or

```
mean(subset(cast2, depth2 > 1000)$salinity2)
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate your help, but I tried this and it is telling me I have an error in my script. Is there any way to do it without using the $?

Comment: What's the error? Are the assumptions in the answer correct? If not please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: Depth below 1000 meters does mean depth2 > 1000, and your assumption are correct, cast2 is the name of the data table, and depth2 and salinity2 are both columns in said data table. The error I'm recieving is Error: unexpected symbol in "mean(subset(cast2, depth2 < 1000)cast2"

Comment: The line of code in your comment is missing `$` and has `cast2` where `salinity2` should be.

Comment: I also tried - mean(subset[cast2, depth2 > 1000, cast2$salinity])
Error in subset[cast2, depth2 > 1000, cast2$salinity] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable - and - mean(cast2[cast2$depth > 1000, "salinity2"])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(cast2[cast2$depth > 1000, "salinity2"]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA -

Comment: The first error is because you used `[` after `subset` - so R thinks `subset` is the name of a data frame but fails to find it. The second warning tells you that the variables are not of type numeric. Unable to help you any further until you provide reproducible data as requested below the question.